# Do I need the binary to do App Store App transfer?

Tags: ios, app-store-connect, app-transfer

I am going to transfer an old app using the App Transfer feature in appstoreconnect. Before transferring it states:

"Source Code and Binary
The source code and binary are not included in the transfer process on App Store Connect. They must be transferred separately to the recipient."

Of course, the source code is not transferred - but the binary? I don't remember how this worked last time, but this time I do not have the source code myself so I cannot easily build a new binary and upload.

I was expecting that when I accept the transfer on the recipient side I only need to fill in some metadata (similar to [this guide](https://support.appmachine.com/support/solutions/articles/80000978437)) and it will be live on the new account - same version, same build, same binary. What do they mean here?

Thanks in advance...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You do not need to build a new build if you meet the new [App transfer criteria](https://help.apple.com/app-store-connect/#/devaf27784ff)

Comment: Thanks, tried it out and was no mention of build in accept process. Still wondering why the documentation states otherwise.